# Is the On Clause Neccessary for Left/Right Outer Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, outer-join

I have the following very simple left outer join in MYSQL:

```
select * from employee left  join department
```

However, this gives me the meaningless error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

But if I simply add an ON clause as shown below, the query works:

```
select * from employee left  join department on employee.departmentId = department.id;
```

So, is the ON clause mandatory?  If I do a "Full Join", it definitely works without an ON clause, but left and right outer joins don't work unless I add an ON clause to them.

By the way there is nothing special about the 2 tables, and there is no foreign key relation between them either.

Edition:

This is the full join that works in MySql:

select * from employee full  join department;

Comment: `Full outer` joins *do* require an `ON` clause. It is cross joins that don't. (and natural joins as well)

Comment: *" If I do a "Full Join", it definitely works without an ON clause"* - in MySQL? Really??

Comment: Yes, here is the one that works:  select * from employee full  join department;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ANSI standard, `on` is required for all join types except `cross join`.  This applies to Oracle and most other databases.

MySQL is a bit different.  This is the syntax diagram in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html):

```
join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

That is, MySQL allows the `on` to be optional for `join`, but not `left outer join` or `right outer join`.  MySQL does not support `full outer join`.  And, to make it more confusing `cross join` is like `join` and *can* accept an `on` clause.

And, you should ignore the MySQL extensions.  *Always* use an `on` clause for left, right, and inner joins.  *Never* use an `on` clause for `cross join`.  I prefer using these to the `natural join` (which you don't ask about), because I prefer to be explicit in the columns being used for the join.

EDIT:

According to [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/270), version 5.6 gets an error on `full outer join` when `left outer join` works.  So this generates an error:

```
select *
from (select 1 as a) t1 full outer join
     (select 2 as b) t2
     on t1.a = t2.b;
```

This also generates an error:

```
select *
from (select 1 as a) t1 full join
     (select 2 as b) t2;
```

And MySQL documentation (through 5.7) is all very clear that `full join` is not supported.  I'm not sure why your query might have worked.

Comment: Thanks for a great and clear explanation.  Just one question, you mentioned MySQL doesn't support full outer join, but this works as I mention above "select * from employee full  join department;"  isn't this a full outer join?  Also, I use Mysql 5.6.10 which I think is the latest version; so they might have added this recently.

Comment: The reason the OP's query worked is because they just aliased the `employee` table as `full` :-)

Comment: @Martin:  Great catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that it work without ON clause, you need the same column name in the 2 tables:
department.departmentId with employee.departmentId

Comment: I wish all these exceptions weren't allowed since they just make everything unnecessarily more complicated.